# How do I add setTimeout to delay the fading animation in the following code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using the following to fade in and fade out elements on `hover`:

```
$(".hidden").hover(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    opacity: 1
  });
}, function() {
  $(this).animate({
    opacity: 0
  });
});
```

I would like to add a delay between opacity `1` and opacity `0` (wait a moment and then fade out the element).

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Do you want to use JS only to accomplish this?

Comment: @Sprottenwels Yes, `setTimeout`

Comment: @alexchenco how about adding that in first animate callback ?

Comment: You already got the answer. Wrap the second call to `animate` in a `setTimeout()`. I'd like to point out that this could easily be done via CSS keyframes, too, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yuu can use the .delay() function http://api.jquery.com/delay/.

```
$(".hidden").hover(function() {
  $(this).delay(1000).animate({
    opacity: 1
  });
}, function() {
  $(this).delay(1000).animate({
    opacity: 0
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gk14nqrx/

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".hidden").hover(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    opacity: 1
  });
}, function() {
  var _this = $(this);
  setTimeout(function (){
    _this.animate({
      opacity:0
    });
  },1000)

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will delay 1 second before fading out. You need to store a reference to $(this) because inside of setTimeout the this is no longer the DOM element.

```
$(".hidden").hover(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    opacity: 1
  });
}, function() {
  var that = $(this);
  setTimeout(function() {
      $(this).animate({
        opacity: 0
      });
  }, 1000);
});
```